# Android Studio - how to securely store SHA-1 key in app

Tags: java, android, encryption, sha1, sensitive-data

I have an android native app and for security reasons now the client says to encrypt SHA-1 key. I checked for the app for generated certificates it shows SHA-1 SHA-256 and MD5. How do I store it all securedly? I referred to these examples but confused about the implementation.In the entire app I looked I am unable to figure out how can I get and store it?In values.xml file all sensitive info is stored like google_api, Firebase details so I need to  store it more securely. How can I do it?

[Links referred](https://gist.github.com/JosiasSena/3bf4ca59777f7dedcaf41a495d96d984)

[Links referred](https://medium.com/@josiassena/using-the-android-keystore-system-to-store-sensitive-information-3a56175a454b)

[Google developers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore)

Comment: SHA-1 key are you talking about? Do you want to implement certificate pinning for a HTTPS connection or do you want to check the certificate of at APK signature or what else. Depending on where the SHA-1 comes from the storage also can change.

Comment: @Robert - I want that SHA-1 should not be accessible by any unauthorized authority?

Comment: @Robert -  In values.xml file all sensitive info is stored like google_api, Firebase details so I need to  store it more securely. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Code from https://gist.github.com/JosiasSena/3bf4ca59777f7dedcaf41a495d96d984 encrypts and decrypts text using your app key. To use it you should first run your app, with calling encrypt on your secret text. Log the encrypted string to logcat. Then read it from logcat and put this string in your source code. Before using this string, you should call decrypt on it and then you can use it later in your code. **Remember** **to remove the code you used to encrypt your string - it was only temporary.**

You can play with this code using this example application:

https://github.com/luskan/EncryptDecryptApp

In MainActivity change SAMPLE_ALIAS to whatever you want.

Encryption is done with this code:

```
        String textToEncrypt = "Your Secret"; // not encrypted yet
        final byte[] encryptedTextArray = encryptor
                .encryptText(SAMPLE_ALIAS, textToEncrypt);
        String encryptedText = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedTextArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and decryption will look as follows:

```
        String encryptedText = "TAxdnTHhyEC34x510mMxqt2nAMrv7dMXWDjr";
        byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
        String decryptedText = decryptor
                .decryptData(SAMPLE_ALIAS, encryptedBytes, encryptor.getIv());
```

Note, that on each encryption the encryptedText will be different - this is a correct behaviour.